# How to search, arrow down and press enter with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autosuggest, webdriverwait

I'm trying to search for a company, arrow down and click enter on inhersight.com

I have the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.inhersight.com/companies")
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("open-search.small-hide.margin-right-20.icon-36.icon-search.reverse.cursor-pointer").click()
elem.send_keys("Apple")
elem.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
```

It doesn't seem to be able to locate and find the element by the class name. I've tried many things but it still doesn't work... I'm lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *search for a company and click enter* on `inhersight.com` instead of as the elements are *Auto Suggestions* so instead of `arrow down` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument('start-maximized')
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.inhersight.com/companies")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".open-search.small-hide.margin-right-20.icon-36.icon-search.reverse.cursor-pointer"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search women-rated companies']"))).send_keys("Apple")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'select2-highlighted')]/div[@class='select2-result-label']/div[@class='weight-medium']"))).click()
  ```

Comment: that's really great, however, it seems to be clicking on the second choice instead of the first one. Any idea?

Comment: Updated the answer as per your comments to click on the first choice. Let me know the status.

Comment: thank you. would you know how to retrieve the url we're at eventually?

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the selections as the company name becomes part of the query string in the URL, with spaces replaced by "-" and all lower case. You can therefore direct .get on this formatted URL. You can add some handling in for if company not found.

```
from selenium import webdriver
company = 'Apple Federal Credit Union' # 'apple'
base = 'https://www.inhersight.com/company/' 
url = base + company.replace(' ', '-').lower()

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)

#other stuff including handling of company not found (this text appears on the page so not hard)
#d.quit()
```