# Unable to select value from autocomplete using protractor

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor, webdriver, display

```html
<select name="Name" class="metaselect ignore" style="display: none;" xpath="1">   <option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" selected="selected">-- New --</option>    <option value="bd434f35-90db-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">AddtoTest</option>    <option value="e8b6fd1b-e2f3-e911-aa64-e16c52c442dc">APINV_EPIC06</option>    <option value="35cfdd50-c47a-e911-aa37-8fe9ba6f0d87">Approve</option>    <option value="70da50aa-e2a3-e911-aa45-8f65b76e1edb">Basic</option>    <option value="5af85ad8-5ac0-e911-aa4f-b51108e06dbe">cont</option>    <option value="1c9b4449-90db-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">Contentgenrat</option>    <option value="7ea80473-ecdd-e911-aa5b-cc08702b7e65">CTB1</option>    <option value="fb0b16cb-5fc9-4938-8cdb-b28b0ac3a065">Default</option>    <option value="5b904ca0-8adb-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">delete</option>    <option value="9cd4dc48-910b-ea11-aa6c-879f4a104148">GP - US Expense Report</option>    <option value="7a87e6ae-75b3-e911-aa4b-a33f065bbcc1">INVOICE</option>    <option value="2860a55d-90db-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">norconnoradd</option>    <option value="df57386a-90db-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">olaa</option>    <option value="f299ad9c-91db-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">qwerty</option>    <option value="2fa1a597-63d9-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">Test1</option>    <option value="14d4d010-5bc0-e911-aa4f-b51108e06dbe">ton</option>    <option value="4e0506f8-bd7a-e911-aa37-8fe9ba6f0d87">View</option>    <option value="15086a03-ebc8-e911-aa54-ce643b10106b">WithNavFieldGroup</option>   </select>
<input "="" class="ui-state-default isCombo [object Object] ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left metaselect" autocomplete="off" name="Name" data-uicombobox="[object Object]" xpath="1">
<a tabindex="-1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" role="button" xpath="1"><span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span></a>
```

```
await element(by.xpath("//span[@class='ui-combobox']//input[@name='Name']")).sendKeys("cont);
```

or

```
this.coreComponent.element(by.cssContainingText("option", value))
```

Our application when run with protractor doesn't recognize the element. Both the above options doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML the element is within a `<select>` tag with `style` attribute as **`"display: none;"`**

So [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) won't be able to focus on the element as it is not **visible**.

---

### Solution

As a solution you need to remove the `style` attribute which is set as **`"display: none;"`** and then interact with the element.

> **PS**: If possible click on the `<select>` element so the options becomes visivle

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions related to `style="display: none;"` in:

- [Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable for element containing style=“display: none;”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848586/expected-condition-failed-waiting-for-element-to-be-clickable-for-element-conta/50852370#50852370)
- [How can i upload files on dropzone.js with style=“display: none;” using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144538/how-can-i-upload-files-on-dropzone-js-with-style-display-none-using-selenium/49144905#49144905)
- [Element changes from display: none to display:block selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58623998/element-changes-from-display-none-to-displayblock-selenium-python/58624255#58624255)

You can find a couple of relevant discussions related to *Auto Complete* / *Auto Suggestions* in:

- [Selecting options from Auto Complete Dropdown using selenium web driver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616513/selecting-options-from-auto-complete-dropdown-using-selenium-web-driver-in-pytho/45617120#45617120)
- [How to search, arrow down and press enter with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684678/how-to-search-arrow-down-and-press-enter-with-selenium/53685021#53685021)
- [How to automate Google Home Page auto suggestion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612605/how-to-automate-google-home-page-auto-suggestion/53613491#53613491)

Comment: The actual problem is with autocomplete input as the data is being fetched by application from input tag. Anything we can do with that element?

Comment: @ShreyasMurali But I'm not sure if autocomplete is ever rendered through select tag. Gimme some time I will provide some autocomplete references

Comment: Usage of enter and arrow keys is also a issue on this element. But I will wait for the references. Thanks!

Comment: @ShreyasMurali Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status. I have added the references for Auto Complete / Auto Suggestions