# Python selenium select drop-down invisible (style =“display: none;”) element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to use python selenium to select an element from a drop-down-bar, and also select the start_date and end_date. Please find the url:

```
<select title="drop_down" name="sType1" class="single_select2" style="display: none;" id="single_select_2">
<option value="">choice</option>
","
<option value="2101">issuance</option>
","
<option value="2701">listing</option>
","
</select>
```

and I use code:

```
driver.get('http://www.sse.com.cn/disclosure/bond/announcement/npcorporate/')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('single_select_2'))
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
s1.select_by_value('2101')
driver.find_element_by_id('btnQuery').click()
```

but the website says:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated' how could I make it visible and able to select it?
```

and I dont know how to put my code to select dates. Could it be possible?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Which line gives an error?

Comment: The page you sent does not have an element with id=single_select_2, even after long time of waiting to be ready.

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, sorry I put the wrong link and now I updated it, should be finehttp://www.sse.com.cn/disclosure/bond/announcement/npcorporate/

Answer (score 0):

The HTML of the `<select>` element with you have shared contains the attribute **`style="display: none;"`**. Presumably,

- This is not your desired element, or
- The element will become **visible** only after certain actions being taken before trying to interact with it.

Else [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) won't be able to **focus** on the `<select>` element to **interact** with it.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Unable to select value from autocomplete using protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207242/unable-to-select-value-from-autocomplete-using-protractor/59209113#59209113)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can see what the problem is, but still do not know the solution..

Answer (score 0):

- Use find_element(By.XPATH, drag_and_drop_xpath)
- Check css style's visibility
- If none or not visibility, add visibility: visible;
- Then you can see visible drop and down

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).